Dynamic decoupling error mitigation
I am trying to understand dynamic decoupling error suppression. What are some python code and resources of qiskit related to dynamic decoupling supported on the latest version (qiskit==1.0)?
Also, is the dynamic decupling technique also supported on fake hardware?
Edit: Using the link below, I tried writing a sample code. This code works in qiskit==1.0 (link)
The sample code is below:
import numpy as np
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import XGate
from qiskit.transpiler import PassManager, InstructionDurations
from qiskit.transpiler.passes import ALAPSchedule, DynamicalDecoupling
from qiskit.visualization import timeline_drawer
from qiskit_ibm_runtime.fake_provider import FakeBrisbane, FakeSherbrooke

def draw(circuit):
    from qiskit import transpile
 
    scheduled = transpile(
        circuit,
        optimization_level=0,
        instruction_durations=InstructionDurations(),
        scheduling_method="alap",
    )
    return timeline_drawer(scheduled)

circ = QuantumCircuit(4)
circ.h(0)
circ.cx(0, 1)
circ.cx(1, 2)
circ.cx(2, 3)

circ.measure_all()

backend = FakeSherbrooke()
backend.set_options(
    max_parallel_threads = 0,  # Use all CPU cores
    max_parallel_experiments = 0,  # maximum no of experiments may be executed parallel
    max_parallel_shots = 42,             # changing 1 to 42
    statevector_parallel_threshold = 16   # qubit should be greater 16 to enable parallelization of matrix multiplication
)

durations = InstructionDurations(
    [("h", 0, 50), ("cx", [0, 1], 700), ("reset", None, 10),
     ("cx", [1, 2], 200), ("cx", [2, 3], 300),
     ("x", None, 50), ("measure", None, 1000)]
)

# balanced X-X sequence on all qubits
dd_sequence = [XGate(), XGate()]
pm = PassManager([ALAPSchedule(durations),
                  DynamicalDecoupling(durations, dd_sequence)])
circ_dd = pm.run(circ)
draw(circ_dd)

raw_counts = []
counts_After_DD = backend.run(circ_dd, shots =1000).result().get_counts()
print(counts_After_DD)

Although, this code is using FakeHardware I do not understand how to effectively use the API InstructionDurations. What I mean is: suppose my circuit is composed of a large number of gates, then how exactly should I use it and exactly on what basis are the time values put in the API?
Also, in this link there is a function called uhrig_pulse_location. What exactly is the use of this function?
Edit1
I think, my question is little too difficult. If would be great if someone can refer to some paper/papers related to dynamic decupling which can help me understand the concept of dynamic decupling theoretically. Thank you for great and continous help.

https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.transpiler.passes.DynamicalDecoupling

Thank you @RefikMansuroglu. The link you provided helped a lot. I have a couple of questions related to some APIs in the EDIT1. It would be really great if you can review it.

Your question lacks focus. Are you trying to understand dynamical decoupling as a protocol? Are you trying to figure out the meaning of the gate duration times in general? In the context of DD? or just what qiskit’s function does?
Your question is al over the place: DD, Qiskit API, gate durations, pulse center placement, etc.

Thank you for the response @diemilio. I want to understand how to use the qiskit function InstructionDurations when I donot know about the circuit because the sample code of qiskit is specifying timing for each gates which is kind of impractical.

You gotta know what gates you apply to use dynamical decoupling. That's the whole point.

@Manu, the code you shared is an example where the idea is to tailor the way DD is being applied for a specific pulse schedule. Therefore, as Refik Mansuroglu just mentioned, you must know the timing of each gate precisely. If what you want is apply DD to a circuit that is going to run on a given backend without having to worry about the exact scheduling, then you're looking at the wrong approach. You should instead look into Qiskit Runtime's error suppression techniques.

Thank you for the response @diemilio. DD I think is still an active area of research.  A small sample code using this link https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/guides/error-mitigation-and-suppression-techniques can be useful to understand DD.
